# Variable from one controller to another

Tags: variables, symfony, controller, routes

I have Client controller. In client controller I  insert data into DB. After inserting, I need to pass name and id of last inserted to controller invoice
in Client contorler I can get data by:

```
$inserted['id'] = $client->getClient()->getId();
$inserted['name'] = $client->getClient()->getName() . ' ' . $client->getClient()->getSurename();
```

How can I redirect to route add_invoice?

routing:

```
add_invoice:
pattern: /add_invoice
defaults: { _controller: AcmeDemoBundle:Invoice:addInvoice }
```

In invoice controller got function:

```
   public function addInvoiceAction($idClient, $nameClient) {...
```

Thanks for suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix your routing to have arguments automatically passed to the method ( via get ). According to symfony naming conventions method arguments use _under_score ...

```
add_invoice:
    pattern: /add_invoice/{client_id}/{client_name}
    defaults: { _controller: AcmeDemoBundle:Invoice:addInvoice }
```

You can generate the route in your Controller like this:

```
$url = $this->generateUrl('add_invoice', array( 
    'client_id' => $inserted['id'], ´
    'client_name' => $inserted['name']
));
```

then redirect from your client controller with:

```
return $this->redirect($url), 301);
```